# List iterator not incrementable error message in C++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

As a newbie I'm trying to implement a sorting function in C++, using the list-class. 
However, running the code I get the error that the list iterator is not incrementable... However it seems very unlikely as it should be incrementable!

code:

```
void shuffle (list<int> &list1)
{
    list<int> smaller;
    list<int> larger;

    if (list1.size() > 1)
    {
        list<int>::iterator it;
        //int it;

        int x = list1.front();


        for (it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); it++)
        {                                       
            if(*it <= x)
            {
                smaller.push_front(*it);
                list1.pop_front();

            }
            else
            {
                larger.push_back(*it);
                list1.pop_front();
            }
            shuffle (smaller);
            shuffle (larger);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print(smaller);
        print(larger);

        //cout << "No sorting needed! The list still looks like: ";
        //print(list1);
    }
    print(smaller);     
    print(larger);
}
```

I implemented this function just in de CPP file, under the main.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming jalf is right, can I just say that I understood "compiling the code, I get the error..." to mean you got a compiler error, not that it compiled but then you got an error when you ran it.

Comment: Changed "compiling the code" to "running the code". I got the exact same error when *running* his code in VS2k8. VS performs a lot of extra validation and bounds-checking on iterators by default, which is what spits out the error he encountered.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for finding the error, but what does it has to be instead of list1.pop_front? list1.pop_back?

Answer (score 13):

Your call to list1.pop_front() removes the element which the iterator is pointing to initially, invalidating it. And an invalid iterator can not be incremented. :)

It took a few minutes to find with the debugger. Just keep an eye on the value of 'it' as you step through the program. I don't know if you know how to use the debugger yet, but if not, do yourself a favor and learn it. It's an invaluable tool.

(By the way, in the future, please be explicit about whether the error occurs at compile-time or while running the program. Your question stated the error occurred when "compiling the program". I just edited the question for you, hope you don't mind. But it's an important distinction, and makes it harder to answer your question accurately)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry about telling where it went wrong. Should keep an eye on it.

But how to adjust the program, the only thing I w

Comment: Well, a simple fix would be to remove "it++" from the for loop, and instead do it just before pop_front(), so the iterator points to the element past the one you're popping. By the way, prefer ++it over it++. :)

Comment: @jalf - good catch. I didn't even look at the code except to get it to compile (adding a dummy print() function).  Just lazy I guess.

Comment: But I can not remove an element of the for-loop! There always must be an element in the for loop. Or do I have to change it to a while-loop?

Comment: Nah, you can remove it. "for (it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end();)" is perfectly legal. In fact, all three "parts" of a for loop may be empty. for(;;) is the idiomatic way to write an infinite loop, for example ("while(true)" gives a warning on several compilers, for(;;) doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to compile the posted code with VS2008 after I commented out the calls to print() and added the following to the beginning:

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my main:

```
> int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//DEFINE LIST
list <int> list1;
//FILL LIST
list1.push_front(5);
list1.push_front(2);
list1.push_front(1);
list1.push_front(9);
list1.push_front(12);
list1.push_front(3);
list1.push_front(4);
//PRINT LIST BEFORE SORTING
print(list1);
//SORT LIST

shuffle(list1);



//PRINT AFTER SORTING

system("pause");




return 0;
```

And the error message is just 1, namely if I debug it (press F5 in VC++ 2008) I get a pop-up that list iterator is not incrementable